# Development on an older mac

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have an old PowerMac G5 lying around and I was wondering if I could use it to create an ios app.
I checked up a bit and it seems I can't install OSX snow leopard or something on it so I'd have an older operating system.

Anyways my question is, can I properly create applications for and iphone or programs for osx with an older version of xcode.
Sorry if this question is stupid.

Comment: Sorry, PowerPC-based Macs are not supported by newer versions of OS X, and there is no iOS toolchain that works on OS's of that generation or on non-Intel machines.

Comment: @VariableLengthCoder That is simply untrue.  See my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but the iOS SDK is only built for Intel targets. A PowerPC-based Mac cannot use it.

Comment: I beg to differ!  Xcode XCode 3.1 was the first to come with the iOS SDK, and the last to support PPC. He could still use that (although it will be limited), and get a proper development experience.  It's still available to download as well.

Comment: Only the components of Xcode 3.1 that do not pertain to iOS development work on PowerPC. The iOS SDK is still unusable. Not to mention you cannot submit an app to the App Store that was built with such an old SDK.